# Using constructor function to add methods

Tags: javascript, prototype

The classic way to create constructor function is like:

```
var Obj = function(param){
    this.param = param;
    this.method = function(){ console.log(this.param); }
}
```

But why i can't do something like this:

```
Obj.anotherMethod = function(){ //some code }
```

(I know about `Obj.prototype.anotherMethod`).

In practical usage i can't understand why use `String.prototype.func` instead of `String.func` to define new method. Is it just because `String` is constructor function and it's impossible to add method to it?

Comment: You're only making a single object of this type.  Try making two objects of that type and then see if your method is as streamlined (hint, you will want to use the `new` operator and you will need methods on the new object, not on the function itself).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are different things.

If you add a method to `Constructor.prototype`, it will be available on all instances of `Constructor`.

You can also add methods to `Constructor` itself. However, instances won't inherit them.

For example,

- `charAt` method is defined on `String.prototype`, so you can use both `"abc".charAt(1)` and `String.prototype.charAt.call("abc", 1)`.
- But `fromCharCode` is defined on `String`, so you can use `String.fromCharCode(65)`, but `"abc".fromCharCode` is undefined.

Comment: Is `fromCharCode` usage is like class static method? And why it is not in prototype?

Comment: @Maxx It isn't in the prototype because it makes no sense to run it on string instances. Not sure if it is like class static methods because I only know prototypical inheritance, not class inheritance.

Comment: `fromCharCode` is static method that does not require object instance. Like almost every methods from **Math**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with prototypal inheritance. Instead of using constructors, you can have objects inherit from other objects using `Object.create()`. You can add members to the parent object *at any time* and they will be available to objects that have the parent as their prototype.

```
var Base = {a: "a"};
Base.b = "b";
var sub = Object.create(Base); // creates a new object with Base as its prototype
Base.c = "c"; // sub.c will be available because Base is its prototype!
alert(sub.a + sub.b + sub.c); // "abc"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kqtm4f8j/

Great article to understand prototypal inheritance patterns:

http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little code that should help. Starting with your constructor:

```
var Obj = function(param){
    this.param = param;
    this.method = function(){ console.log(this.param); }
}
```

Now make an instance:

```
var inst = new Obj("testParam")
//now use it
console.log(inst.param) // logs: "testparam
```

Now add another parameter to Obj:

```
Obj.anotherParam = "TestParam2"
console.log(Obj.anotherParam) // <-- Works
console.log(inst.anotherParam) // <-- but this is Undefined on the instance
```

But if you add it to the prototype:

```
Obj.prototype.anotherParam = "TestParam2"
console.log(inst.anotherParam) // <-- this now works as expected
```

The takeaway is that when you add it to the prototype it becomes available to all instances. If you simply add it to the constructor, only the constructor function has the parameter. There are a lot of other ways to do this in Javascript, but understanding the prototype object is a good place to start.